# Laravel.get one related record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

There is two models: Category and Post.

```
class Category extends Model
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post','category_id');
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{   
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
//Get data
      $data = Category::with(['posts' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
          }])->get();
```

In this case, all categories are displayed and only one post. I need to get from each category the one record post.
**Example:** 
Category 1 - Post1
Category 2 - Post2
Category 3 - Post5
Category 4 - Post15
One category - one last post this category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Category` with many `Post`s, but you just want to get the most recent post so you would add another relationship.

```
// Category.php
class Category extends Model
{
    // This gets ALL posts
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post','category_id');
    }

    // This gets the most recent post
    // I am ordering by created_at instead of ID, but you can use ID 
    // if it makes sense for your application)
    public function mostRecentPost()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Post','category_id') // hasOne is the key here
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

Then when you want to use it...

```
$data = Category::with('mostRecentPost')->get();
```

Comment: Oops! I misunderstood the question :-)